# Обработка файла - LINQ

Tags: pascal, linq, pascalabc.net

Задача:

LinqObj6°. Исходная последовательность содержит сведения о клиентах фитнес-центра. Каждый элемент последовательности включает следующие целочисленные поля:
<Код клиента> <Продолжительность занятий (в часах)> <Год> <Номер месяца>
Для каждого месяца определить суммарную продолжительность занятий всех клиентов за все годы (вначале выводить суммарную продолжительность, затем номер месяца). Если данные о некотором месяце отсутствуют, то для этого месяца вывести 0. Сведения о каждом месяце выводить на новой строке и упорядочивать по убыванию суммарной продолжительности, а при равной продолжительности — по возрастанию номера месяца.

Делал так:

```
begin
  ReadAllLines('C:\Ilya\AlgoРитмы\Файл1.txt').GroupBy(x -> x.ToWords().Last())
  .Select(x -> (x.Sum(y -> StrToFloat(y.ToWords()[1])), x.Key)).OrderByDescending(x -> x.Item1)
  .ThenBy(x -> x.Item2).Select(x -> Format('{0} {1}', x.Item1, x.Item2)).Println(NewLine);
end.
```

однако, не знаю как сделать так, чтобы если данные о некотором месяце отсутствуют, то для этого месяца выводилось 0.

Comment: Сделать это одним Linq-выражением принципиально? Если нет - делайте `ToDictionary`, а потом через `TryGetValue` читайте, если записи нет, то он вернет значение по умолчанию (0 для числовых типов)

Comment: Можете написать код как сделать с помощью словаря, например?

Comment: Можно попробовать еще взять `Enumerable.Range(1, 12)` и "сджойнить" с нашей последовательностью. Сейчас сочиняю решение.

Answer (score 1):

Можно взять последовательность `Enumerable.Range(1, 12)` и сделать с ней *левое внешнее соединение*:

```
var res = Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
            .GroupJoin(
                File.ReadLines("...")
                    .Select(s => s.Split())
                    .GroupBy(p => p.Last())
                    .Select(g => (Month: int.Parse(g.Key),
                                  Duration: g.Sum(p => float.Parse(p[1])))),
                x => x,
                y => y.Month,
                (x, y) => (Month: x,
                           Duration: y.FirstOrDefault().Duration))
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.Duration)
            .ThenBy(p => p.Month)
            .Select(p => string.Format("{0} {1}", p.Month, p.Duration));
```

Вариант со словарем, который читается гораздо легче:

```
var dict = File.ReadLines("...")
               .Select(s => s.Split())
               .GroupBy(p => p.Last())
               .ToDictionary(g => int.Parse(g.Key),
                             g => g.Sum(p => float.Parse(p[1])));
dict = Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
                 .ToDictionary(x => x,
                               x => dict.ContainsKey(x) ? dict[x] : 0);
foreach (var pair in dict.OrderByDescending(p => p.Value).ThenBy(p => p.Key))
    Console.WriteLine("Месяц: {0}, продолжительность: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
```

<sub>код на шарпе, в паскаль переведете самостоятельно</sub>